# Distinguishing rows in my table

Tags: java, arrays

First ill start off by explaining what I have, then what I am trying to do.

Currently, my program creates a deck of cards using arrays (I dont want enum's). Then it shuffles the cards into a random order and prints a table of 7 X 7 cards.

What I want to do is to be able to ask the user what row their card is in, then flip the table so that the row they selected is now a column.

How do I distinguish the rows (like in a 2d array) so that I can then ask the user what row their card is in
and
How do I flip this table so that the row becomes the column

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck;
    private int currentCard;
    String[][] multi = new String[7][7];

    public Deck() {
        String[] Faces = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
        String[] Suits = { "♠", "♣", "♦", "♥" };

        deck = new Card[52];
        currentCard = 0;

        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
            for (int face = 0; face < 13; face++) {

                deck[(face + (suit * 13))] = new Card(Suits[suit], Faces[face]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        currentCard = 0;

        SecureRandom randomNumber = new SecureRandom();

        for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++) {
            int second = randomNumber.nextInt(52);

            Card temp = deck[first];

            deck[first] = deck[second];
            deck[second] = temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        int k;
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                System.out.print(deck[k++] + "    ");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return (s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck theDeck = new Deck();
        theDeck.shuffle();
        theDeck.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: ...and the problem/ question is?

Comment: The operation you're trying to do is called "transpose." There might be some stuff built already out there that can do this

Comment: @StefanFreitag the problem/question is "What I want to do is to be able to ask the user what row their card is in, then flip the table so that the row they selected is now a column."

Comment: @j.seashell I think your right. Ill go look into it and try it out, ill let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Basically you could continue to store the cards of the deck in the given array. To map from the array position to a row and column you can use e.g. the `/` (to find the row) and `%` (to find the column in the row) operators.
- Concerning the flipping: think of a method like the implemented `toString()`. Let the new method have a `boolean transposed` as parameter. Depending of the value (true/false) you could print the cards either the one or the other (transposed) way - leaving the model untouched.